# Powershell script creates new folders as @{Folder=Test-folder}/

Tags: powershell, directory

Here is my code.    Pretty straight forward except when it creates the actual folder the folder name rather than being the folder name, ie "Test-Folder" it creates "@{Folder=Test-folder}/"

```
$Folders = Import-Csv "folders.csv"

ForEach ($Folder in $Folders) { 
New-Item -Path $Folder -ItemType directory
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$Folder` is not a `[String]`; consider it a row of the CSV. Try `$Folder.Folder` (there's clearly a `Folder` column in the CSV which is represented by a `Folder` property in the imported object).